# Using PeriodicImpulse for Side Input in Apache Beam Pipeline

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming

Attempting to use PeriodicImpulse to periodically update Side Input in Apache Beam pipeline.

Here is the Flink Overview
[image: Flink Overview]

For some reason the pipeline is stuck at the task where the two branches merge. Specifically at the "Enrich Event With Aggrefest Data". This is the PTransform that uses the side input.

Everything seems to be working fine (e.g., a new PeriodicImpulse is generated every 60 secs). Seems that the side input and main input windows do not match and therefore here is no progress at the "Enrich Event With Aggrefest Data" step?

Here is the code:

```
def main(argv, input_source, impulse_source, output_sink):
    """
    Main entry point into the execution of the pipeline.
    """
    known_args, pipeline_args = Options().parse(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    data_pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    team_shared_handle = shared.Shared()

    aggrefest_side_input = (
        data_pipeline
        | 'Periodic Impulse' >> impulse_source
        | 'Load Aggrefest Data' >> beam.ParDo(LoadAggrefestData())
    )

    (
        data_pipeline
        | "Read input from Kafka github_events topic" >> input_source
        | "Decode JSON from String" >> beam.ParDo(LoadJSON())
        | TransformEvent()
        | "Set Event Timestamp" >> beam.ParDo(SetEventTimestamp())
        | "Define Event Window" >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60))
        | "Initialize Event Enrichment" >> beam.ParDo(InitializeEnrichment())
        | "Enrich Event With Aggrefest Data" >>
        beam.ParDo(EnrichWithAggrefestData(),
            aggrefest_side_input=beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(aggrefest_side_input, default_value={})
        )
        | "Enrich Event With Team Data" >> beam.ParDo(EnrichWithTeamData(team_shared_handle))
        | "Set Enrichment Metadata" >> beam.ParDo(SetEnrichmentMetadata())
        | "Encode JSON into String" >> beam.ParDo(DumpJSON())
        | "Write output to logging pipeline" >> output_sink
    )

    result = data_pipeline.run()
    if not pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming:
        return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = [
        "--runner=PortableRunner",
        "--streaming",
        "--sdk_worker_parallelism=0",
        "--checkpointing_interval=60000",
        "--min_pause_between_checkpoints=60000",
        "--max_bundle_size=5000",
        "--environment_expiration_millis=0",  # 0 is default (never expire)
        "--externalized_checkpoints_enabled",
        "--retain_externalized_checkpoints_on_cancellation",
    ]
    args.extend(sys.argv[1:])
    source = create_kafka_input(settings.KAFKA_SOURCE_GITHUB_EVENTS_TOPIC)
    impulse_source = PeriodicImpulse(
        start_timestamp=Timestamp.now(),
        fire_interval=60,
        apply_windowing=True
    )
    sink = beam.ParDo(LogFn())
    main(argv=args, input_source=source, impulse_source=impulse_source, output_sink=sink)

class LoadAggrefestData(beam.DoFn):
    """
    A DoFn to load Aggrefest data from S3.
    """
    def process(self, element):
        event_timestamp = Timestamp.now()
        aggrefest_client = AggrefestClient()
        aggrefest = aggrefest_client.get_aggrefest_data()
        filtered_aggrefest = {}

        for service in aggrefest.keys():
            filtered_aggrefest[service] = {}
            if 'slack' in aggrefest[service]:
                filtered_aggrefest[service]['slack'] = aggrefest[service]['slack']
            if 'team_email' in aggrefest[service]:
                filtered_aggrefest[service]['team_email'] = aggrefest[service]['team_email']
          
        yield filtered_aggrefest


class EnrichWithAggrefestData(beam.DoFn):
    """
    A DoFn to enrich an element with Aggrefest data.
    """

    def process(self, element, aggrefest_side_input):
        {os.getpid()}: Side Input: {aggrefest_side_input}")
        repo_name = element.get('github', {}).get('repository', {}).get('name')
        if repo_name in aggrefest_side_input and 'enrichment' in element:
            service_aggrefest = aggrefest_side_input.get(repo_name, {})
            element['enrichment']['team'] = {
                'channel': service_aggrefest.get('slack'),
                'email': service_aggrefest.get('team_email')
            }
            element['enrichment']['service'] = {
                'service_tier': service_aggrefest.get('service_tier'),
                'pagerduty_escalation_policy': service_aggrefest.get('pagerduty_escalation_policy'),
                'envoy_services': service_aggrefest.get('envoy_services'),
                'image_type': service_aggrefest.get('image_type')
            }
        yield element
```

Comment: The part "Slowly updating side input using windowing" of [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/) document should be doing the exact same thing. Is your "LoadAggrefestData" loading a single value or an iterable of values? And how is the "EnrichWithAggrefestData" consuming the value(s)?

Comment: About windowing, "Beam uses the window(s) for the main input element to look up the appropriate window for the side input element. Beam projects the main input element’s window into the side input’s window set, and then uses the side input from the resulting window. If the main input and side inputs have identical windows, the projection provides the exact corresponding window."  See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs-windowing.

Comment: Updated the code to include "LoadAggrefestData" (loading a dict of values) and "EnrichWithAggrefestData". 

Regarding the comment on windowing, yes, that is exactly what I expected based on the official documentation. Unfortunately that does not occur. As the pipeline does not return any element. Rather elements remain stuck at the last task in the diagram.

Comment: I tried to define a timestamp, window and trigger for the side input as well. While doing so, the pipeline returns some elements at the after the last task but only a subset of them. The pipeline restarts due to the following errors: ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: call already closed``` and  ```java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to org.apache.beam.sdk.util.WindowedValue```

Comment: Here are the new lines added to the ```aggrefest_side_input``` for reference:


```| "Set SideInput Timestamp" >> beam.ParDo(SetEventTimestamp()) | "Define SideInput Window" >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60), trigger=trigger.AfterProcessingTime(60), accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)```